# How do you say "You are something"?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

How do you say "You are something" in German?

I'd like to say it in this context :

Why can't you meet my Parents??!! You're something, you know that?!

Here's my attempt. Can one say:

> Du bist (et)was.

Comment: Can you put it in a wider context? I only know "you're something else". In which situation you use this?

Comment: @halirutan "Du bist ja `ne Marke!" :D

Comment: Could you add a bit more context? What you provided could be read in two ways: either as "Come on, you are not nothing, you know that?!" or as "You're unbelievable, you know that?!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implying that you mean that someone is special, you can use

> Du bist schon was!

or

> Du bist was Besonderes!

Comment: Note that when talking about someones achievements in life you might use "Du bist [schon|wirklich] wer!". However "wer" implies a male, "was" is neuter (so be very cautious if you use it with a female) and the similiar term "Du bist [schon] eine/-r!" has a completely different meaning.

Comment: Why does "wer" imply male? "Wer ist die Frau da drüben?"

Answer (score 3):

> "Du bist mir ja Einer!"

Expresses bewilderment at someone for doing something outrageous. Far more common than "Du bist schon was!"

Comment: Das wäre negativ oder aufziehend; beides scheint nicht zur Originalfrage zu passen. So wie ich die Frage verstehe, fragt DerPolyglott33 nach einer Aufmunterung.

Comment: In the context of an unwillingness to meet someones parents I consider it appropriate.

Comment: I know this expression in an humorous way only. However, @Robert, I'm not sure how OP it really meant. Might be that my knowledge of English is too little and I don't see any obvious connotation in "You're something", but for me it's not clear if this is meant to be ironically or upset or really simply encouragingly.

Answer (score 0):

Ich würde das nicht wörtlich übersetzten, sondern etwas sagen wie "Du musst Dich doch nicht verstecken". Wenn die Eltern auf erbrachte Leistungen Wert legen, könntest Du "Du musst Dein Licht doch nicht unter den Scheffel stellen" oder "Du hast doch Sachen, auf die Du stolz sein kannst" sagen.